# C++ split string by another string as whole

Tags: c++, string, c++11, boost

I want to split a string by any occurrence of `and`.

First of all I have to make it clear that I do not intend to use any `regex` as a delimiter.

I run the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> results;
    std::string text=
        "Alexievich, Svetlana and Lindahl,Tomas and Campbell,William";
    boost::split(
        results,
        text,
        boost::is_any_of(" and "),
        boost::token_compress_off
        );
    for(auto result:results)
    {
        std::cout<<result<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the results are different from what I expect:

```
Alexievich,
Svetl







Li


hl,Tom
s




C
mpbell,Willi
m
```

It seems every character in the delimiter acts separately while I need to have the whole `and` as a delimiter.

Please do not link to [this boost example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#idp430824992) unless you are sure that it will work for my case.

Comment: That's kind of what `is_any_of` means, that it matches *any* of the characters in the string. The third argument is a *predicate* which means it can be any callable object including lambdas. Another problem is that the [`boost::split`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/split_idp205739088.html) seems to be *character* based, and not "word" based.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, thanks for your comment. What to replace with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old-fashioned way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> results;
    std::string text=
        "Alexievich, Svetlana and Lindahl,Tomas and Campbell,William";
    size_t pos = 0;
    for (;;) {
        size_t next = text.find("and", pos);
        results.push_back(text.substr(pos, next - pos));
        if (next == std::string::npos) break;
        pos = next + 3;
    }

    for(auto result:results)
    {
        std::cout<<result<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Packaging into a reusable function is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: If the scanned text contains "Copeland, Amit"... you will "split" on the contained "and".

Comment: if find() fails, you have an error calling `substr(pos, npos-pos)`

Comment: @DavidThomas Re: contained "and". Nothing in the problem statement suggests that the program should not split on that. Quoth the OP: *"I want to split a string by **any** occurrence of `and`."* (emphasis mine) Re: `substr` - no I do not have an error. The program is in fact expected to call `substr(pos, npos-pos)` eventually, and it works just fine.

Comment: I stand corrected. I knew that substr would take npos and return the rest of the string, but had never seen that any value longer than the string does the same thing. Hmmm. Thanks for the lesson.

Answer (score 1):

`<algorithm>` contains search - right tool for this task.

```
vector<string> results;
const string text{ "Alexievich, Svetlana and Lindahl,Tomas and Campbell,William" };
const string delim{ " and " };
for (auto p = cbegin(text); p != cend(text); ) {
    const auto n = search(p, cend(text), cbegin(delim), cend(delim));
    results.emplace_back(p, n);
    p = n;
    if (cend(text) != n) // we found delim, skip over it.
        p += delim.length();
}
```